# Why we don't integrate intital velocity in body cast equation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, integration

On [this](http://www.fxyz.ru/%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8B_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB/%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BA_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%83/%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BA_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%83/) site I've found a formula for calculating the $x, y$ coordinates for a body throwed by an angle to a horizon.

It looks like this:
   $$x(t) = V_0  t  \cos(\alpha);  $$
   $$y(t) = V_0  t  \sin(\alpha) - gt^2/2;  $$

It's clear to me that term $(g t^2)/2$ was received by the integration of $gt \, dt$.
But, I don't understand, why didn't we integrate $V_0 t \sin(\alpha)$ part of the equation?
Why do we integrate only $gt$ term?

Comment: Everything were integrated. That's why there is a $t$ in $v_0 t\sin{a}$.

Comment: @Physicist137, so, the original equation was then x(t)=V0*sin(a), is that's right?

Comment: Well, no. You must integrate velocity to get position. Hence, original equation was: $v_y(t) = v_0\sin a - gt$ and $v_x = v_0\cos a$.

Comment: @Physicist137, now I understand, thanks.

Comment: $\int V_0 sin(\alpha) dt = V_0 sin(\alpha) t$

Comment: Why do we start with gt, not just simple g?

Comment: Oh I get it I get it, it's because g is acceleration. And to receive velocity from acceleration, we need to integrate. Hence there's gt. And to receive displacement of a material point in space, we integrate both terms (that are functions of the velocity of this point) respective to t. That's why sin and cos of alpha stay unaffected, same as the power of V.